# node.js/discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, discord.js

Trying a simple test, but I'm getting an error from this line:
client.user.setPresence('game', { type: 'PLAYING' });

**VSCode's logs:**

```
C:\Users\dvmvged\Documents\mao>node . whoa.js
C:\Users\dvmvged\Documents\mao\whoa.js:9
client.user.setPresence('game', { type: 'PLAYING' });
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dvmvged\Documents\mao\whoa.js:9:13)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11←[39m
```

**whoa.js**

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.Client();

    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log("Logged in.");
        client.login("token");
    });

    client.user.setPresence('test', { type: 'PLAYING' });
```

**package.json:**

```
{ 
    "name":"test-bot",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "description":"simple test",
    "main":"whoa.js",
    "dependencies":{ 
        "discord.js":"^11.5.1"
    },
    "devDependencies":{ 

    },
    "scripts":{ 
        "test":"echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author":"no one",
    "license":"ISC"
}
```

**NPM version: 6.11.3**

**Node.js version: 12.12.0**

**Discord.js version: 11.5.1**

***EDIT:*** Just to let you know, I tried .setActivity and .setGame. same error.

Comment: I assume you're passing an actual token into `.login()` and not actually `"token"`?

Comment: @c_sagan nope, I'm just trying to hide my token

Comment: Try moving `.login()` outside the `.on()` scope. See [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Comment: Also note that `.login()` returns a promise, so by the time you call `.setPresence()`, you haven't received the response from the `.login()` call. Try `.login().then(client.user.setPresence())`

Comment: same error, I tried everything you told me to do

Comment: In that case, there could be something wrong with the token you're using?

Comment: Nice point, I'll check it. Thank you.

Comment: same error. I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening here is a consequence of the Node.js event loop. You call an asynchronous function, `.login()`, and immediately attempt `client.user.setPresence()` before the response from `.login()` arrives.

Try

```
  .login("token")
  .then(client.user.setPresence("game", { type: "PLAYING" }));
```

See [Node Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)

Comment: Tried it, same error.

client.login("token");
client.user.setPresence('game', { type: 'PLAYING' });

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of null

Answer (score 0):

`.user` has not yet been populated when you called him. I'm gonna annotate the order at which things happen here.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

// #1
client.on('ready', () => {
    // #3
    console.log("Logged in.");
    client.login("token");
});

// #2
client.user.setPresence('test', { type: 'PLAYING' });
```

You only have a guarrantee of .user existing after the client is ready.

Whenever you use a *callback* in node (not just in node!), you pass a function as an argument to something.

That callback may be **scheduling** that function to run on a later time. On this specific case case, it schelules the function which has `console.log` to run on a future **event** of the client "being ready".

Comment: This worked. But it didn't output anything to the console. Also, I want to change the status of the bot later in the code. Can I use the same .setPresence function later?

Comment: So ive actually never made a discord bot. From a quick look at docs seems that you should call "login" on the outside (not in the ready callback). When the client sucessfully authenticates it should emit the "ready" event.

Comment: That is correct, you should log in (with your bot’s token) outside of the ready event’s callback. Upon a successful login, the ready event will fire and the stuff in that callback function you provide will run. At that point, `client.user` should no longer be `null`, and you’ll be able to use methods like `.setPresence()`. Basically, place your method inside the ready event’s callback, and you can place the `.login()` at the start or the end of your js file, doesn’t matter (just not inside a callback that won’t run yet, and obviously it shouldn’t be before `client` is defined).